# Removal of noise : Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I was trying to remove some unwanted figures from my images while thinning an image. To an extent it worked. But still there are some , due to which in the final stage the require output forms a different shape.I tried in different images, but none of them are working properly.Can please anyboldy tell where am going wrong

```
I = imread('img.jpg');
I = rgb2gray(I);
I = uint8(255*mat2gray(I));
I = medfilt2(I,[5 5]);
I = histeq(I,256);
myfilter = fspecial('gaussian',[3 3], 0.5);
myfilteredimage = imfilter(I, myfilter, 'replicate');
I=imresize(I,[128 128]);
figure,imshow(I);
```

input
   [image]

```
I1=edge(I,'canny',0.375);
I2=edge(I,'canny',0.1);
I = imsubtract(I2,I1);

si = imdilate(I,strel('line',3,0));
se = imerode(I,strel('line',3,0));
I = imsubtract(si,se);
figure,imshow(I)

si = imdilate(I,strel('disk',1));
se = imerode(I,strel('disk',2));
I = imsubtract(si,se);
figure,imshow(I);
```

[image]

we can see there are patterns similar to the input but due to the presence of those noises inbetween the line, when I execute next line it distorts the whole pattern

```
 I = imfill(I,'holes');

[L num]=bwlabel(I); %%number of connected objects found in binary%%%
A=[];
for i=1:num
    a=find(L==i);
    A(i)=size(a,1);
end
[b indxA]=max(A);

L2(128,128)=0;

for i=1:num
   if A(i)>=0.9*b
    L2(find(L==i))=1;
   end
end

figure,imshow(L2);
```

Comment: Try eroding the image once before filling holes- should work

Comment: I tried it, but when I do so  it looses the intersection points.